# Как сделать динамический массив структур с объединением? (C)

Tags: c, структуры, динамические-массивы

Пользователь вводит отель, выбрав соответствующий пункт меню, и он должен куда-то сохраняться (занимать какую-то память, но чтобы он не стерся заранее), чтобы можно было обратиться к нему через указатель, а сам этот указатель положить в двусвязный список. Сохраняю отели в массив, но потом с этим массивом по сути не работаю. Я что-то очень сильно не догоняю, но сломав голову, поискав, и спросив у чата-гпт, так ответ и не пришел. Спокойно добавляет один отель с русским вводом, а на 2-ом крашится с -1073740940 (0xC0000374) (утечка памяти же, да?). В чем проблема и какие советы можете дать?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "funcobj.h" // структуры + функции
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
struct ctn
{
    char country[25];// страна
    char town[25];// город
    char name[25];// название
};

struct hotel
{
       struct ctn r;
       int clas;// класс (от 1 до 5)
       float moneylive;// стоимость проживания в день
       float moneyroad;// стоимость пути в обе стороны
       union
       {
           char bonus[25]; //4->5 какие доп.услуги есть.
           int exc; // 1->3 или сколько есть экскурсий.
       } b;
};




struct node
{
       struct hotel *data;// хранится отель
       struct node *next, *prev;// указатели на предыдущий элемент(отель) и на следующий
};

struct nodes
{
    struct node *begin, *end;// начало и конец списка
};

void inps(char a[], int c)
{
    char * ptmp;// инициализация указателся на перенос строки в переданных строках
    fgets(a, c, stdin); // ввод строки и её сохранение в массив
    ptmp = strchr (a, '\n');// нахождение переноса строки и запись его адреса в переменную
    if ( ptmp ) *ptmp = '\0';// замена переноса строки концом строки
    else while (getchar()!='\n');// удаление остальных символов в случае большой длины строки
}

struct hotel input_hotel (void)
{
    system("CLS");
    struct hotel h;// инициализация отеля
    nullh(h);// обнуление всех полей отеля
    char * ptmp;// инициализация указателся на перенос строки в переданных строках
    puts ("Страна");// вывод сообщения
    inps(h.r.country, 25);
    puts ("Город");// вывод сообщения
    inps(h.r.town, 25);
    puts ("Название отеля");// вывод сообщения
    inps(h.r.name, 25);
    puts ("Класс (от 1 до 5)");// вывод сообщения
    do
    {
        scanf ("%d*c", &h.clas);// ввод класса
    }
    while (h.clas > 5 || h.clas < 1);// если число меньше 1 или больше 5, то число надо набрать заново
    puts ("Стоимость проживания за один день");//вывод сообщения
    do
    {scanf ("%f%*c", &h.moneylive);} while (h.moneylive <0);//ввод стоимости до тех пор, пока это число не будет меньше 0
    puts ("Стоимость проезда в оба конца");//вывод сообщения
    do {scanf ("%f%*c", &h.moneyroad);} while (h.moneyroad <0);// ввод стоимости до тех пор, пока это число не будет меньше 0
    if(h.clas <=3)
    {
        puts("Сколько экскурсий доступно?");
        scanf("%d*c", &h.b.exc);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Какие дополнительные услуги предоставлены?");
        inps(h.b.bonus, 25);
    }
    return h;//возвращает структуру отель
}

struct hotel addhmass(struct hotel m[], struct hotel h, int *c)
{
    m = realloc(m, (*c+1)*sizeof(struct hotel));
    //m[*c]= h;
    //*c = *c+1;
    m[*c] = h;
    (*c)++;
    return m[*c-1];
}

int main (int argc, char*argv[])
{
    char file[60]; //инициализация переменной имени файла
    int menu, c = 0; // инициализация переменной для работы с меню
    struct nodes hs; // инициализация списка с начальным и конечным элементом
    struct hotel *hh;
    hh = malloc(sizeof(struct hotel));
    makenull(&hs); // обнуление списка
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus"); // выставление локали для отображения русских символов
    SetConsoleCP(1251); // установление кодовой страницы 1251 для компилятора
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установление кодовой страницы 1251 для вывода в компиляторе
    if (argc>1)
    {
        strcpy(file, argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        puts ("Введите имя файла."); // вывод сообщения
    gets (file); // ввод названия файла с расширением
    }
    hs = read_file(file, hh, &c); // ввод списка из файла или он остается пустым
    do
    {
       system ("CLS"); // очистка экрана
       puts ("1. Добавить отель.");
       puts ("2. Показать список.");
       puts ("3. Вывести отели с минимальной стоимостью проживания определенного класса.");
       puts ("4. Удалить элемент списка.");
       puts ("5. Рассчитать среднюю стоимость тура на неделю в отели определенного класса.");
       puts ("6. Выйти.");
       scanf("%d%*c", &menu);
       switch (menu)
       {
              //case 1: addhmass(hh, input_hotel(), &c); hs = new_node (hs, &hh[c-1]); break;
              //case 1: input_hotel(hh, &c); hs = new_node (hs, &hh[c-1]); break;
              case 1: hs = new_node(hs, addhmass(hh, input_hotel(), &c)); break;
              case 2: show (hs); break;
              //case 3: search (hs.begin); break;
              case 4: hs = delete_node (hs); break;
              case 5: sm(hs.begin);
       }
    }
    while (menu!=6);
    if (write_file (file, hs.begin))//
        puts ("Файл сохранен.");//
    else
        puts ("Файл не сохранен.");//
    delete_list (hs);//
    //free(hh);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://pythontutor.com/render.html#mode=edit это сайт визуализатор ваших данных. Там ограничения есть, но уменьшив их можно увидеть визуально что, где, куда. Мне это помогло в реализации динамических структур.